# Restoring GCP project not restoring the project to firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have a project that I created on firebase and then deleted. When I tried to restore it through GCP it shows as if Iv'e restored the project, but if I refresh the deleted projects list the project is still there. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
[image: A gif of what happens]

Iv'e tried restoring it and going out of the page, and while I can then acces the project on GCP, I still can't on firebase and when I try on firebase, I can no longer acces it on GCP either.

Comment: Warning: You can recover most resources if you restore a project within the 30-day period. Some services have delays in restoring and you might need to wait some time for services to be restored. Some resources, such as Cloud Storage or Pub/Sub resources, are deleted much sooner. These resources might not be fully recoverable even if you restore the project within the 30-day period. [link](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#shutting_down_projects)

Answer (score 0):

Update: as Jhon Hanley said, it taks some time for the updates to be handled. now the project is fully restored.
Though it is still wierd that it didn't take the project of the deleted list...